downstream api - wasm (blazer) application troubles
I have an azure function protected by an application registration.
I have an blazor application again protected by an application registration.
I am trying to set up a downstream api (azure function) from my blazer application.
I have allowed the blazor spn to have access to the scope from the azure function spn.

I have used the boiler plate code and used the wizard within visual studio to create the blazer project with Microsoft entra id authentication.
When I attempt to log on I get an error saying
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
      DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.

If I go through the connected services wizard again and remove the extra api (downstream api) it works perfectly fine.
Has anyone got any advice on this ?
Thanks a lot.

It seems like the downstream API (Azure Function) authentication setup might be causing authorization issues for your Blazor application. Double-check the authentication configuration for both applications to ensure proper permissions and scopes are granted. Additionally, review any custom authorization policies or middleware that might be affecting the authentication flow between the Blazor application and the downstream API.
